# Select all rows with max value on a column for all the id in array

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table stamps with the columns:

```
LOC(Blob)
LOCDTL
LOCTIME
CARRIERTYPE
CARRIERID
```

I want to get the row corresponding to MAX(LOCTIME) value for each id coming from front-end side in an array in the query itself.

I have tried this possibility but none works the way I want to.

```
SELECT X(LOC), Y(LOC), LOCDTL, LOCTIME, UPPER(CARRIERTYPE), CARRIERID
FROM  LOC_EVENT_CARRIER_REPO
WHERE UPPER(TRIM(CARRIERTYPE)) = "VESSEL"
  AND UPPER(TRIM(CARRIERID)) IN (35, 69,70,71,72,73,74)
  AND LOCTIME IN (SELECT MAX(LOCTIME) FROM LOC_EVENT_CARRIER_REPO
                  WHERE UPPER(CARRIERTYPE) = "VESSEL"
                    AND CARRIERID IN (35, 69,70,71,72,73,74))
group by CARRIERID;
```

Comment: How does your query not work?

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right. Find the last row, with `MAX(LOCTIME)` for every `CARRIERID` in the provided list of id's

```
SELECT X(LOC), Y(LOC), LOCDTL, LOCTIME, UPPER(CARRIERTYPE), CARRIERID
FROM  LOC_EVENT_CARRIER_REPO e
JOIN (
      SELECT CARRIERID, MAX(LOCTIME) maxlt
      FROM LOC_EVENT_CARRIER_REPO 
      WHERE UPPER(CARRIERTYPE) = "VESSEL"
                    AND CARRIERID IN (35, 69,70,71,72,73,74)
      GROUP BY CARRIERID 
    ) m ON e.CARRIERID = m.CARRIERID AND e.LOCTIME = m.maxlt
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need a correlation clause rather than `GROUP BY` in the subquery:

```
SELECT X(LECR.LOC), Y(LECR.LOC), LECR.LOCDTL, 
       LECR.LOCTIME, UPPER(LECR.CARRIERTYPE), LECR.CARRIERID
FROM LOC_EVENT_CARRIER_REPO LECR
WHERE UPPER(TRIM(LECR.CARRIERTYPE)) = 'VESSEL' AND
      LECR.CARRIERID IN (35, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74) AND
      LECR.LOCTIME IN (SELECT MAX(LECR2.LOCTIME)
                       FROM LOC_EVENT_CARRIER_REPO LECR2
                       WHERE UPPER(TRIM(LECR2.CARRIERTYPE)) = UPPER(TRIM(LECR.CARRIERTYPE)) AND
                             LECR2.CARRIERID = LECR.CARRIERID
                      );
```

Your version matches the maximum time over all the carriers, rather than just carrier-by-carrier.

Notes:

- In a well maintained database, you should not need `UPPER(TRIM())` for type values.
- You definitely would never use `UPPER(TRIM())` on numeric values, and `CARRIERID` looks numeric.
- Assuming there are no duplicate time values, you do not need an outer `GROUP BY`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You should qualify all column references in a query that has more than one table reference.